# php fwrite function

Tags: php

i want to save data in .txt file when i run my code data not save in txt
get output error how can i save this?

**Error**

`Couldn't write values name.txt to file`

**Template PHP**

```
<?
class Template {
    public $template;

    function load($filepath) {
        $this->template = file_get_contents($filepath);
    }

    function replace($var, $content) {
        $this->template = preg_replace('[{#}(.*){#}]', "", $this->template);
        $this->template = str_replace("#$var#", $content, $this->template);
    }

    function publish() { eval("?>".$this->template."<?"); }

} ?>
```

**PHP**

```
include "template.class.php";

$template = new Template;
$template->load("templates.txt");
$template->replace("name", "Robert Lomees");
$template->publish();

$file = "name.txt";

$savethis=$template->publish();
$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $savethis) or die("Couldn't write values $file to file!");
```

**templates.txt**

```
#name#
```

Comment: Check that you have enough permission to write to the name.txt file.

Comment: Need more information. Your question doesn't show any effort.

Comment: The second die() should be: or die("Couldn't write values $savethis to file!");   Is $savethis really a string? With content?

Comment: i need to save this function $template->publish();

Comment: @djot: Even fwrite($fp,false); will work.

Comment: @Indranil: don't know, came to my mind because he uses this call to publish() twice, and perhaps it does not return anything (usefull)

Comment: output show Robert Lomees with above error i need to save this Robert Lomees word in file.txt

Comment: @djot: Even if it wrote a blank variable to the file, it wouldn't return the `or die()` part. :) Writing would be successful. But yes, without looking at the full code, I don't think the `$template->publish()` needs to be called twice.

Comment: @MSona Please edit your post!!! Not in here!

Comment: Hello i have update information

Comment: `$savethis` is `NULL`, so `fwrite` returns a false-y value hence the die. You might be interested in output buffering functions but the question is old. Voting to close as not a real question due to not seeing that writing nothing into a file will make PHP return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

Apply handlers as in below code. and try to get where is problem.

```
<?php
$filename = 'test.txt';
$somecontent = "Add this to the file\n";

// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
if (is_writable($filename)) {

    // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
    // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
    // that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
?>
```

Comment: Following errors and warnings would tell the OP something equally verbose without creating needless code.